# Oracle WebCenter Site: Authentication failed for user fwadmin. Internal error code: -100

Tags: oracle, webcenter, webcenter-sites

I'm facing an issue with a new application that I'm creating for Oracle WebCenter Sites, I'm trying to set up my standalone application in WebCenter Sites using Asset API, so when I built, I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
 with name 'globalServiceImpl' defined in file  
[C:\Oracle\WebCenter\Sites\11gR1\App_Server\apache-tomcat- 
7.0.42\Sites\webapps\wcs-uir\WEB-
INF\classes\com\uir\wcs\services\global\impl\GlobalServiceImpl.class]:  
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  
Could not instantiate bean class 
[com.uir.wcs.services.global.impl.GlobalServiceImpl]: Constructor threw 
exception; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException:  
Authentication failed for user fwadmin. Internal error code: -100 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ins 
tantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)  
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)  
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)  
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)  
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)  
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)  
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)  
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)  
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)  
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)  
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Could not instantiate bean class[com.uir.wcs.services.global.impl.GlobalServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed for user fwadmin. Internal error code: -100  
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)  
 ... 27 more  
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed for user fwadmin. Internal error code: -100  
at com.fatwire.system.SessionFactory.newSession(SessionFactory.java:92)  
at com.uir.wcs.services.global.impl.GlobalServiceImpl.<init>(GlobalServiceImpl.java:37)  
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)  
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)  
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)  
... 29 more
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use in my service :

```
 public GlobalServiceImpl()  {  
   this.ses = SessionFactory.newSession("fwadmin", "xceladmin");  
   this.adm = (AssetDataManager) ses.getManager(AssetDataManager.class.getName());  
   this.servicesManager = (ServicesManager)ses.getManager( ServicesManager.class.getName() );  
   this.siteService = servicesManager.getSiteService();  
   this.siteManager = (SiteManager)ses.getManager(SiteManager.class.getName());  
  }
```

I really have no idea what to do.
i'll be grateful if some one can help me.
best regards.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use REST API as it works properly. Asset API seems to have session issue.